# How to use reflection along with LINQ to Entities to get an entity property's value?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection

I try to execute the following statement:

```
int count = this.objectReportsRepository.All()
            .Count(or => (int)or.GetPropertyValue("ReportingUserId") == reportModel.ReportingUserId
            && or.GetPropertyValue("Reported" + target + "Id") == reportModel.GetPropertyValue("Reported" + target + "Id")
            && DbFunctions.TruncateTime((DateTime)or.GetPropertyValue("ReportDate")) == serverTimeToday);
```

However, I get an error:
*System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetPropertyValue[QuestionReport](InterpretumDAL.QuestionReport, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

**GetPropertyValue** is actually an extension method that I wrote on my own to use reflection:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue<T>(this T sourceObject, string propertyName)
{
    return sourceObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(sourceObject, null);
}
```

I want to execute the LINQ to Entities statement written on the top of my question, because I have different Report entities. For example, I have QuestionReport, UserReport, TagReport, etc. entities. I do all the same with them, but they have a different meaning. The QuestionReport entity stores reports for Question entities. The UserReport - for User entities and so on. So, instead of writing the same code *n* times, I want to user Reflection.

The only thing I could think of is to add a **ToList()** method call after the **All()** method call, but by doing this I actually load all entities in memory and only after this I Count the thing I want to count, instead of counting it with a simple query.

Help? Anyone? :)

Comment: If you want to execute C# code as part of your query then you have to fetch all the data into memory first, EF can't convert your extension method into SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build expression tree in order to use it against linq to entities, try this expression.

```
var or = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ObjectReport));
var cond1 = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(or, "ReportingUserId"), 
    Expression.Constant(reportModel.ReportingUserId));
var cond2 = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(or, "Reported" + target + "Id"), 
    Expression.Constant(reportModel.GetPropertyValue("Reported" + target + "Id")));
var cond3 = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(DbFunctions), 
        "TruncateTime", 
        Type.EmptyTypes, 
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(or, "ReportDate"), typeof(DateTime?))),
    Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(serverTimeToday), typeof(DateTime?)));
var cond = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.AndAlso(cond1, cond2), cond3);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<ObjectReport, bool>>(cond, or);

int count = this.objectReportsRepository.All().Count(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

No offense man, but why even use entity framework if you're going to misuse generics like this?

Your repository should be a `Repository<T>` so that when you perform .All() you can just directly select the property value that you need via Func. Then in your code, wherever you need a `Repository<QuestionReport>`, everything is automagically set up and your queries can simply perform

```
var questions = repository.All(questionReport => questionReport.Question == "How old are you");
```

You should **never** use reflection in any kind of loop. It's very inefficient.

Anyway, if you're still set on this, you'll have to do the .All().ToList() then loop through it again to do your logic, because (to retiterate): you're doing it very, very wrong.

Comment: +1 for this, the way you are using reflection is starting to become a code smell and you should consider alternative options.

Comment: I'd like to say too that I'm not trying to be rude or anything, it's just that what I've observed from the examples is discomfiting.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you misunderstood my question or whether I've done it wrong (I am not trying to be rude, I'm really not sure). My All() method returns the entity set. I mean, having the example above, I have a Repository<QuestionReport> and its All() method actually returns an IQueryable<QuestionReport>. When I want to execute the statement you wrote, I just do repository.All().Where(qr => qr.Question = "How old are you?"); So, why is this wrong and how is it different from the code you wrote (I am trying to understand again, not being rude)?

Comment: Okay, but why are you using reflection to get at your properties then? Your count function call should be **much** simpler if you're not returning an anonymous type, on the order of `{etc}.Count(or => or.ReportingUserID == reportModel.ReportingUserId && {etc})`. You shouldn't need to use reflection at all if you're retrieving the actual type.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do now, but it's over-engineering. Unless you can have all 3 of your data model classes inherit from an interface that has the property you're looking for, I wouldn't go down this route. Reflection is not a good idea.